# Schedule activity in solidity

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to schedule some tasks in solidity itself like cron job without triggering transactions from the external parties?

It is something like a cron job that wakes up at a particular time and does a certain job.

Answer (score 1):

Chainlink Keepers is a smart contract automation solution. It has a CRON-style scheduler. It also enables users to create their own triggers based on time, schedule, on-chain state changes, etc...
Here is the documentation: https://chain.link/keepers

Comment: So it does require external intervention, right ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to schedule some tasks in solidity itself like cron job without triggering transactions from the external parties?

It is not, because that's how Ethereum blockchain works.

Comment: I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Is it not possible with Ethereum Alarm Clock?

Comment: There are only good questions, but unfortunately, answers are not those what we are looking for.

Comment: Ethereum Alarm Clock is an external party, thus by your definition, not a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

A message, or transaction, from an external account is what activates a smart contract's code and allows it to perform some function.  These transactions are created, signed with an external accounts private key and hold some data that tells the contract what to do.

Contract accounts **do not have private keys**.  These accounts cannot instantiate transactions and therefore must be activated by an external account to perform any action.

Comment: I appreciate your response. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use external tools. For example [Defender](https://openzeppelin.com/defender/) provides several tools, and one of the is called autotask, which you can use to send transactions on a regular basis to your contracts.

I'll leave the documentation [here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/defender/autotasks).

Disclaimer: Defender is an Open Zeppelin product, I do work for them, but they do not know Im posting this answer here, and Im not directly a member of the Defender project, Im just trying to help.